# Releasing custom made NSObject class in iOS App

Tags: ios, memory-management, nsobject, dealloc

I have a Class which I have created as an NSObject.
This class has a number of properties of different types and 
methods etc.

When I instantiate this class in my App (say in the main View Controller) I
immediately send it a release call when I am finished using it. ie:

```
MyObject *myObject = [[MyObject alloc] initWithParameters:parms];
[myObject doSomeMethodCall];
[myObject release];
```

So my question is:
When I release myObject, does it automatically release all of the declared objects, variables, etc.
that I declared in the MyObject .h file?

OR

Do I need to create a custom release method which releases all of these?

I ask because of memory management issues.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement a `dealloc` method in your object and use that method to release any resources that you own.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW4

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [mainSprocket release];
    [auxiliarySprocket release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Important note: you never call a dealloc method on an object, it's invoked automatically by the runtime when it's time to clean up.

Comment: This is good but I have a NSDictionary object that when I release it in the -(void)dealloc call, it crashes my app... I can't figure out why..

Comment: Do you retain that dictionary anywhere else?

Comment: No but I assign values from the dictionary to other objects such as strings. These other objects are released anyway before I try to release the NSDictionary but it still crashes the app. Also, when I put the [super dealloc] in my -(void)dealloc method it crashes my app. The funny thing is that it only crashes my app if I am not running it with the Debugger. If I run it with debugger and have the [super dealloc] calls it does not crash. strange..

Comment: I figured out the problem regarding the [super dealloc] and NSDictionary. Its a bit complicated to post and really has more to do with some errors I made. anyway this all works good in my app now.

Answer (score 0):

From [iPhone - when is dealloc for a viewcontroller called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577635/iphone-when-is-dealloc-for-a-viewcontroller-called):

> Dealloc will run when the last
>   reference to an object has been
>   released.

so when you release your object it will run dealloc. So put all your releases and such into your object's dealloc method.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, it will call the dealloc method on the myObject. In the `dealloc` method of myObject, you should release all the instance variables that myObject has. Also, don't forget the `[super dealloc]`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as `Zigglzworth` and it was the position of the `[super dealloc]` call.  I had it at the start of my `-(void)dealloc` method and it was causing a crash every time.  Moved `[super dealloc]` to the end of the method after the variable release statements and now it works just fine.