# when is the dealloc method called?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

When exactly is the `dealloc` method called? I've found that (in a lot of examples) much of the NS variables are released in the method it's instantiated in, but when synthesizing a component they place the release in the dealloc method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Apple reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-dealloc) document clearly states
Subsequent messages to the receiver may generate an error indicating that a message was sent to a deallocated object (provided the deallocated memory hasn’t been reused yet).

You never send a dealloc message directly. Instead, an object’s dealloc method is invoked indirectly through the release NSObject protocol method (if the release message results in the receiver's retain count becoming 0). See Memory Management Programming Guide for more details on the use of these methods.

Subclasses must implement their own versions of dealloc to allow the release of any additional memory consumed by the object—such as dynamically allocated storage for data or object instance variables owned by the deallocated object. After performing the class-specific deallocation, the subclass method should incorporate superclass versions of dealloc through a message to super:

> **Important:** Note that when an application terminates, objects may not be sent a dealloc
>   message since the process’s memory is automatically cleared on exit—it is more efficient 
>   simply to allow the operating system to clean up resources than to invoke all the memory 
>   management methods. For this and other reasons, you should not manage scarce resources in 
>   dealloc

Another SO question [iPhone - when is dealloc for a viewcontroller called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577635/iphone-when-is-dealloc-for-a-viewcontroller-called)

Answer (score 0):

When you load the nib file, there's got to be an owner which is an 
object that exists in the application. If you open the nib file in 
interface builder you will see a proxy icon that represents the owner 
of the nib file. You can make connections to it but the connections 
are not established UNTIL the nib file is loaded and you specify who 
the onwer really is.

Anyways, you can have an outlet (e.g. an i-var) connected to the top 
level UI object in the nib file, usually the window. When you load 
the nib file and specify the owner that i-var will now point to the 
UI object. Let's say it is a window. Eventually when you decide to 
get rid of the UI objects you simply release the owner and if it 
reaches a retain count of zero the dealloc method will get called. 
Then the dealloc method in the owner should release it's i-vars 
(instance variables). So let's say the i-var that you connected to 
the window is called window. Then you should have something like 
this:

- (void)dealloc {
[window release];
[super dealloc];
}

That should then cause the window to reach a count of zero. Then 
the window's dealloc should get called and it will subsequently 
release all the retains on the subviews, and the subviews will reach 
a retain count of zero and they will subsequently release all the 
retains on their subviews, and so on until everything is dealloced.

It's been a while since I did AppKit (Cocoa) programming but I think 
this is still true.

There's an application from Omni called OmniObjectAlloc or something 
like that which should be very helpful in looking at your app and 
figuring out if everything is getting dealloced. I used ObjectAlloc 
from NeXT/Apple but I don't know if they still provide it. Look for 
it, I would imagine it's still there.

Answer (score -1):

Its based on the scope of the object that you actually create or retain. 
Whenever the retaincount is brought back to 1, dealloc method will be called by its own. 
This is only applicable for MRC, not in ARC.

One good note is keep track of the objects that you create, let it not leak in your implementations.

Comment: `dealloc` is called when the retain count would have been decremented to 0.  Since decrementing the RC to 0 would be pointless, that isn't done.   But the object is still very much alive when the "retaincount is brought back to 1".