# When is dealloc called and how does it work?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [when is the dealloc method called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630660/when-is-the-dealloc-method-called)

When is the `dealloc` method called? Is it called automatically or not?

If I write

```
UIButton *Btn = [UIButton alloc];
[Btn release];
```

then is `dealloc` called now beacuse the reference count is zero?

If not, then when and how does it work? What is `super`?

When it's called, is everything I release inside `dealloc` be released or not? For example, suppose `dealloc` is called, and we realese `btn1` and `btn2`, but `btn2`'s reference count is still two. When `dealloc` is called, is `btn2` also released and its reference count one, or does it become zero?

Comment: Should be noted that there might not have been any kind of allocation at all when you call `alloc`; it is an implementation detail.  Example; `[NSString alloc]` doesn't allocate anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `dealloc` will be automatically sent to an object that has no more owners (i.e. every object  that retained it, `release`d it)
- `[super dealloc]` invokes the dealloc method of the superclass (the parent class for the current object). Since almost every class in the Cocoa framework is subclassed at least from `NSObject`, this line is necessary for proper memory release.