# When does dealloc method call?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to iphone and I want to know when does -(void) dealloc method call. I know it is used to release objects but can we release any kind of object using dealloc method? And is it necessry to add this method and why we write [suped dealloc] in dealooc method?

share your views.

Comment: This depends if you're building an ARC or non-ARC project. For new projects, I would highly recommend using ARC, in which case `dealloc` is used much less frequently. (And you don't use `[super dealloc]` with ARC.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the explanation straight from APPLE's Docs

> The NSObject class defines a method, dealloc, that is invoked
>   automatically when an object has no owners and its memory is
>   reclaimed—in Cocoa terminology it is “freed” or “deallocated.”.

**Important**

> Never invoke another object’s dealloc method directly.

**Here is the answer why we call `[super dealloc]`?**

> You must invoke the superclass’s implementation at the end of your
>   implementation. You should not tie management of system resources to
>   object lifetimes
>
> When an application terminates, objects may not be sent a dealloc
>   message. Because the process’s memory is automatically cleared on
>   exit, it is more efficient simply to allow the operating system to
>   clean up resources than to invoke all the memory management methods.

Answer (score 0):

You Can release object those which is allocted, copy, or retain by you this is simple to understand. You can not release object those are not allocating by you means autorelease object, which ios detect for no more use in memory ,that time autorelease pool drain that time those object released from memory automatically.

And object dealloc method called when object retain count becomes zero.

Comment: ARC takes care of all `@properties` belonging to the class though, so it is often not necessary to write a dealloc method at all when using ARC.
If you do write one, `[super dealloc]` should come last, as this is the final cleanup done by the superclasses.

Answer (score 0):

You never send a dealloc message directly. Instead, an object’s dealloc method is invoked indirectly through the release NSObject protocol method (if the release message results in the receiver's retain count becoming 0). See Memory Management Programming Guide for more details on the use of these methods.

Subclasses must implement their own versions of dealloc to allow the release of any additional memory consumed by the object—such as dynamically allocated storage for data or object instance variables owned by the deallocated object. After performing the class-specific deallocation, the subclass method should incorporate superclass versions of dealloc through a message to super:

Refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630660/when-is-the-dealloc-method-called)