# Dealloc method isn't called when i release perticular object

Tags: objective-c

I have created an object using `alloc/init` method, and after I release it `-dealloc` should be called immediately as per documentation. I set a breakpoint on `-dealloc` method but it isn't hit, and my `-dealloc` method is not called.

Please tell me what is the reason behind that, and what is use of dealloc method in objective c ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559295/difference-between-release-and-dealloc-in-objective-c

Comment: Post some code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-dealloc` method is not always called when you expect it to be called. The runtime might also have issued a `-retain` on your object for internal reasons.

It's also possible that you have (directly or indirectly) caused an extra `-retain` to be issued. If the retains/allocs and releases are not balanced, you'll never see `-dealloc` called. It helps to turn on the Static Analyzer, to make sure your calls balance.

Just follow the memory management rules, don't second guess the runtime, and let the memory management system do its job.

The answers to [When does dealloc method call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853438/when-does-dealloc-method-call?rq=1) may help you understand what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

because **it still has reference**. that means its reference count not reached to zero. i don't know your code, where it is referencing. but it is not calling that means somehow still it has reference. it may be because of **strong** relationship or **parent-child** relationship

> all Objective-C objects are allocated on the heap, so they must
>   therefore be deallocated somewhere if you are not to run out of
>   resources.
>
> This gave way to the reference counting method, which is still used
>   today: each object keeps count of any references held to it. If you
>   receive an object and you want to keep it, you retain that object,
>   incrementing its reference count. When you are done with it, you
>   release it, which decrements its reference count. Once that count
>   reaches zero, it is inferred that no one is referencing the object and
>   it is automatically deallocated using the -dealloc method.
>
> Additionally, an object could be told to “release at some point in the
>   (hopefully) near future” using autorelease pools. The idea is that
>   somewhere on the stack (typically at the start of a thread or while
>   responding to input events) an autorelease pool is created and pushed
>   onto a stack. Any object can then be sent an -autorelease message, and
>   it is assigned to that pool.
>
> When the pool object is deallocated, it simply sends a -release
>   message to all its assigned objects. That way, any objects that are no
>   longer used (i.e. they haven’t been explicitly retained) are then
>   deallocated.

Answer (score -1):

The `dealloc` is called (at more cases) whenever your object is released. You can't directly call this method.

```
@interface myViewController:UIViewController
{
    NSString *myStr;
}

@end
```

Here the `dealloc` method in the @implementation of `myViewController` will be called (at most cases) when the `myViewController` object is released, not when `myStr` is released.

Although you don't have to use if you ARC.