# My retainCount is increasing?

Tags: iphone, memory, dealloc, retaincount, popviewcontrolleranimated

am trying here to build rss reader , the problem that when user finish read artical and press back the dealloc don't called

and i got retainCount 6 & some times 7 !!

i have lots of customized panels

when back button pressed the view is poped and no dealloc called ?!

.h file :

```
 @interface ArticalViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate,ArticalBottomPanelDelegate,ArticalContentFetcherDelegate> {

    UIWebView * description_;
    UIActivityIndicatorView * ind_;
    ArticalModel * artical_;
    NSString * content;
    UIButton * faceBookShareBtn_;

     UIBarButtonItem * btnSharePanel_;


     CustomTopToolBar * topToolbar_;

     ArticalBottomPanel* articalBottomPanel_;
     MovingSharePanel * movingSharePanel_;

     int fontSize;
     BOOL favoStatus;
     ArticalContentFetcher *datafetcher_;     

 }


@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIWebView * description;
@property (nonatomic,retain ) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView * ind;
@property (nonatomic,retain) ArticalModel * artical;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton * faceBookShareBtn;


@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet  CustomTopToolBar * topToolbar;
@property (nonatomic , retain) IBOutlet ArticalBottomPanel * articalBottomPanel;
@property (nonatomic , retain) IBOutlet MovingSharePanel * movingSharePanel;

@property (nonatomic , retain) ArticalContentFetcher *datafetcher;




-(void) loadArtical:(ArticalModel * )artical;
- (void) loadArticalContentFromInternet;
-(void) changeFavoriteBtnIcon:(BOOL) status;
-(void)backBtnPressed:(id) sender;

-(IBAction)openPostBtnPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m File :

```
    #import "ArticalViewController.h"


    @implementation ArticalViewController


    @synthesize description=description_;
    @synthesize artical=artical_; 
    @synthesize ind=ind_;

    @synthesize  faceBookShareBtn=faceBookShareBtn_;

    @synthesize topToolbar=topToolbar_;
    @synthesize articalBottomPanel=articalBottomPanel_;
    @synthesize movingSharePanel=movingSharePanel_;
    @synthesize datafetcher=datafetcher_;

    - (void)dealloc
    {
        NSLog(@"ArticalViewController : dealloc");
        [description_ release];
        [ind_ release];
        [artical_ release];
        [content release];
        [faceBookShareBtn_ release];

        [btnSharePanel_ release];


        [topToolbar_ release];

        [articalBottomPanel_ release];
        [movingSharePanel_ release];
        [datafetcher_ release];

        [super dealloc];
    }

    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark - View lifecycle

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        fontSize=100;


        [self.articalBottomPanel setDelegate:self];
        [self.movingSharePanel setArtical:self.artical];
        [self.movingSharePanel setParentView:self];


        [self.topToolbar.rightButon setFrame:CGRectMake(260 , 3,  50, 30)];
        [self.topToolbar.rightButon addTarget:self action:@selector(backBtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.topToolbar.rightButon setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.topToolbar.leftButon setFrame:CGRectMake(10 , 3,  50, 30)];
        [self.topToolbar.leftButon setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button-toolbar-post-link"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [self.topToolbar.leftButon addTarget:self action:@selector(openPostBtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        self.topToolbar.label.text =self.artical.category;
      //  [label release];

        //Navigation Buttons
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;

        //Check if artical is favorited or not
        [self changeFavoriteBtnIcon:[Favorites chechArtical:self.artical]];



        [self.description setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self.description setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1px-post-views-background"]]];

        if([[self.artical content] length] >1){
            NSLog(@"[[self.artical content] length] >1");
           [self loadArtical:self.artical];
        }else {
            NSLog(@"else");
            self.datafetcher=[[ArticalContentFetcher alloc ]init ];
            [self.datafetcher setArticalContentFetcherDelegate:self];
             [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadArticalContentFromInternet) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

        }




    }
    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark ArticalConnectionFeed Delegate Methods
    -(void) articalContentConnectionDoneWithArtical:(ArticalModel *)artical {
        NSLog(@"articalContentConnectionDoneWithArtical");
        [self loadArtical:artical];
    }
    -(void) articalContentConnectionFailed{
        NSLog(@"articalContentConnectionFailed");

    }
    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark ArticalBottomPanelDelegate Delegate Methods

    -(void) openPanelFired{
        NSLog(@"openPanelFired");
        [self.movingSharePanel movePanel];
      //  [self.articalBottomPanel.btnOpenSharePanel setHidden:YES];
    }

    -(void) fontBtnFired:(int)font{
       // NSLog(@"fontBtnFired : %d",font);
        if(font==1){
            [self.description stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '90%'"];
        }else {
            [self.description stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '-10%'"];
        }
    }
    -(void) favoBtnFired {
        NSLog(@"favoBtnFired");
        favoStatus=[Favorites processArtical:self.artical];
        [self changeFavoriteBtnIcon:favoStatus];
    }

    -(void) changeFavoriteBtnIcon:(BOOL) status{
        if (status){
            [self.articalBottomPanel.btnFavo setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"active-star.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }else {
            [self.articalBottomPanel.btnFavo setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark UIWebView Delegate Methods
    -(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
        if([InternetConnection getInternetStatus]){
            if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
                return NO;
            }
            return YES;
        }else {
            [InternetConnection ShowNoInternetAlert];
            return NO;
        }


    }

    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
        [self.ind stopAnimating];
    }


    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Class Methods
    -(void) loadArtical:(ArticalModel * )artical{
        NSLog(@"loadArtical");
        [self.artical setContent:[artical content]];
        [self.artical setCategory:[artical category]];


        NSString * style=[[NSString alloc ] initWithFormat:@"<style> #offline img{display:none;} .wrap{text-align:right;line-height:22px; direction:rtl;} .title{font-size:20px;margin-bottom:5px;} .date{font-size:13px;} .cat{font-size:13px;} </style>"];

        if([InternetConnection getInternetStatus])
            NSLog(@"[InternetConnection getInternetStatus] : true");
        content=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@<div class='wrap' ><div class='title'>%@</div><div class='date'>%@</div><div class='cat'>%@</div>%@</div>",style,[self.artical title],[DateProcessor getInternetDateAndTimeForArticals:self.artical.pubDate],[self.artical category],[self.artical content] ];
        [ self.description loadHTMLString:content baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];

        [style release];
    }

    - (void) loadArticalContentFromInternet{
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        [self.datafetcher loadArticlContentWithID:self.artical.ID];
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run ];
        [pool release];


    }
    -(void)backBtnPressed:(id) sender{
            NSLog(@"backBtnPressed");

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];


    }

    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark IBActions      


    -(IBAction)openPostBtnPressed:(id)sender{
        if([InternetConnection getInternetStatus]){
            [InternetConnection openExternalUrl:self.artical.link];
        }else{
            [InternetConnection ShowNoInternetAlert];
        }


    }

    @end
```

Addition :

when i was invoking the Artical i used

```
avc=[[ArticalViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ArticalViewController" bundle:nil];
    avc.artical=[self.feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    [self.navCon pushViewController:avc animated:YES];

    [avc release];
```

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577635/iphone-when-is-dealloc-for-a-viewcontroller-called

Comment: i looked before sending this Q , but am asking about my case , what's wrong with my code !?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I found that the best way to trace retain counts and missing retain-release pairs is using *Instruments*. Hit Profile (<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) and choose *Leaks* template. Even if leaks will not be discovered automatically, retain changes are logged so you can manually trace additional retains. To do that, find your class name in *Object Summary* when selected *Allocations* instrument. If you can't find it, this means that all instances were deallocated. Otherwise click on the arrow that appears when you select class name:
[image: Select the class name and click on the arrow to view living instances]
 You will see all living instances of your class:
[image: Select the instance and click on the arrow to view its retains/releases]

If you suppose that there are some instances that should be already deallocated, select one and click on the arrow that appeared next to object address. Now you should see any retain or release that was invoked on this object with method name that was performing this action:
[image: Double click to see what line of code invoked this retain/release]

*RefCt* column shows retainCount after action was invoked, and when you double click on any retain/release, instruments will show you line of code where this was performed:
[image: Responsible lines are highlighted]

As you see, object is added to an array and never removed from it.

In my experience this is the fastest and easiest way to find memory leaks that *Leaks* instrument would not automatically detect. I think another good practice is to look at *#Living* in *Object Summary* to ensure that number of living instances are exactly as you'd expect.

Answer (score 9):

You have no reason to care what the retain count is.  Just make sure you balance your retains and releases.

Answer (score 5):

Strange as it may seem, `retainCount` is not useful at all for counting your retains. Things get retained for other reasons than you calling `[myObject retain]` or `[[MyClass alloc] init]` etc.

It's better to ignore `retainCount` and learn the [memory management rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html). `retainCount` will make you more confused. If you're developing only for iOS 5, it's better to forget about memory management and use [ARC](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios5/).

Answer (score 0):

`NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:` retains its target, which in this case is `self`. Also, self is the delegate of a few things here, usually you don't want to retain delegates so if you've written those protocols check that you are not doing that.

Comment: ur right ,  i checked my delegates , now i have retainCount 2 , but after i called [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; , the retain count is 4 !!

Comment: i added [self retain]; before [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; and dealloc called correctly  , but is it true to call [self release]; !? is this the solution ?!

Comment: the retain count when you pop might be different depending on whether or not your loadArticalContentFromInternet method has completed on the other thread. You should cancel this thread before you pop. Aimlessly calling release is dangerous. Figure out where else you are being retained and release appropriately.